# How to correctly watch for changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive, a controller and a provider:

```
var note = angular.module('note', []);

note.controller('noteController',function($scope,$note){
    $scope.queue = $note.getQueue();
});

note.directive('note',function($note){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    template:
        '<div ng-repeat="notification in queue">' +
            '<p>{{notification.message}}</p>' +
        '</div>',

    link: function(scope,element,attr, noteController){
        noteController.$watch($note.queue,function(){
            scope.queue = $note.getQueue();
        })
    },
    controller: 'noteController'
  }
 });

note.provider('$note',function(){

  this.$get = function($timeout){

    var queue = [];

    function note(){
    }

    note.prototype.show = function(msg){

        var notification = {
            'message': msg
        };

        queue.push(notification);
    };

    return{
        getQueue: function(){
            return queue;
        },
        note: function(){
            return new note();
        }
    }
  }
})
```

In my applications main module, i inject both the provider and the note module.

I create an instance of `note` and fire up it's `show()` method. This works fine, the note is being displayed.

However, if i do the exact same thing in another extern module, notecontroller.queue won't get updated.

I have created a simple plnkr to show the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/dtPF4rBocLw9gWrmO3cP?p=preview

Comment: More code in plunker = less chance to get an answer. Trim down your example to the minimal, essential part to maximize your chances of getting attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted in the question isn't relevant to the problem you're facing, the problem is in your validator, you're calling `preventDefault()`. The default behavior of the input element is cancelled, and you aren't calling `$digest` manually, so there is nothing to trigger the digest loop.

Two solutions:

1. Remove the `e.preventDefault();`
2. Call `scope.$digest()` in your `keydown` handler

http://plnkr.co/edit/HtjnNmored70rAPOOMg6

Comment: You saved my day, thank you very much. 
I used the second solution and everything works fine.